# How to Increase compute limit above 200k compute

Tags: cpi, transaction, compute-budget, compute, instruction

I am making a CPI to a heavy instruction in another program and running into insufficient compute limit issues. How do I increase the compute limit for my instruction. I once saw up to 1.4M compute units for an instruction.

Answer (score 4):

https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction

> Use ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ units: number }) to set
> the new compute budget. The value provided will replace the default
> value. Transactions should request the minimum amount of CU required
> for execution to maximize throughput, or minimize fees.

```
const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ 
  units: 1000000 
});

const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ 
  microLamports: 1 
});

const transaction = new Transaction()
.add(modifyComputeUnits)
.add(addPriorityFee)
.add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      toPubkey: toAccount,
      lamports: 10000000,
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't really found great docs on it, but I believe the way it works is that your transaction's *first* instruction must be this:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/00929f836348d76cb3503d0ba5f76f0d275bcc66/sdk/src/compute_budget.rs#L34

Frontend implementation here:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/web3.js/src/programs/compute-budget.ts

Code demonstration in the tests here:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/web3.js/test/program-tests/compute-budget.test.ts